# Python - multiprocessing with large strings slower

Tags: python, string, performance, nlp, multiprocessing

I am working on a textual analysis of a large sample of 10Ks (about 150,000) and desperately trying to speed up my program with multiprocessing. The relevant function loads the txt files, parses them with some RegExp and saves them as "clean":

```
def plain_10k(f):
input_text = open(ipath + "\\" + f, errors = "ignore").read()

# REGEXP

output_file = open(opath + "\\" + f, "w", errors = "ignore")
output_file.write(input_text)
output_file.close()
```

I try to perform this function over a list of file names as follows:

```
with Pool(processes = 8) as pool, tqdm(total = len(files_10k)) as pbar:
for d in pool.imap_unordered(plain_10k, files_10k):
    pbar.update()
```

Unfortunately, the program seems to be stuck as it is not returning (i.e. saving clean txt files) anything. Even with a small list of 10 files, nothing happens.

What is the problem here?

If it is relevant: the size of the input txt files ranges from 10kb to 10mb with the majority beeing smaller than 1mb.

I am quite new to Python, so the code above is the result of hours of googling and certainly not very good. I am happy about any comments and suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance!